# How to loop through an object in React Native

Tags: object, react-native

```
const data = {
  apple: {
    type: 'fruit',
    image: './fruit/apple.jpg'
  },
  orange: {
    type: 'fruit',
    image: './fruit/orange.jpg'
  }
  carrrot: {
    type: 'vegetable',
    image: './vegetable/carrot.jpg'
  }
}
```

I am trying to build a search function to loop through an object to return the items I need.

for example, if I want all the fruit, the image of apple and orange will be rendered.

I need something like this:

```
list = []
for item in data:
    if item.type == 'fruit':
        list.append(item)
return list
```

What is the proper code in React Native? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first check whether you data is valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys allow to iterate over properties:

```
const fruits = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].type === 'fruit')
.map(key => data[key]);
```

First, we make an array of object properties, then we filter the keys for type fruit, And finally map the key to the object to provide an array of fruits.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Input 
const data = {
 apple: {
  type: 'fruit',
  image: './fruit/apple.jpg'
  },
  orange: {
    type: 'fruit',
    image: './fruit/orange.jpg'
  },
  carrrot: {
    type: 'vegetable',
    image: './vegetable/carrot.jpg'
  }
}

var expectedResult =  Object.values(data).filter((item)=>  item.type === "fruit")
```